# How to apply the Two stage least square

Tags: time-series, arima, least-squares, autocorrelation, consistency

Given the arma (1, 1) model: $y_t=ρy_{t−1}+v_t+θv_{t-1}$
I found that OLS estimate for ρ is not consistent and that $y_{t-2}$ can be an instrument for $y_{t-1}$, can anyone help me know how to perform theoretically a two stage least square in this case?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216254/time-series-and-instrumental-variables/216270#216270