# Why is the assumption that the disturbances of a dynamic linear regression model are serially uncorrelated important and how could it be tested?

Tags: regression, econometrics, dynamic-regression

I'm a little bit confused about this assumption here. If we considered it is a dynamic linear regression model, then disturbance correlation is part of the probability. So this assumption  is comparatively meaningless. I just wonder if someone could explain this mathematically and intuitively.

Comment: How do you arrive at the conclusion that something which is "part of the probability" - what do you mean by this? - is "comparatively meaningless"?

Comment: This thread may be useful: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216254/time-series-and-instrumental-variables/216270#216270

Comment: Thanks for your comments and I think I have figured it out. It is that I misunderstood the meaning of dynamic linear regression. Hope you have a happy Christmas!