# Deriving Invertibility Condition for This ARMA(1,2) Process

Tags: time-series, self-study, arima, moving-average

This is self study.

Given: $y_t = \mu + x_t + z_t$, where $x_t = e_t + \theta e_{t-1}$ and $z_t = \beta z_{t-1} + u_t$. Also $|\beta|<1$ and $e, u$ are independent of each other and are both iid normal with mean 0 and variances $\sigma^2_e, \sigma^2_u$ respectively.

1. The first part of the question is to show that $y_t$ is ARMA(1,2). Substituting $x_t, z_t$, we get:

$$y_t = (1-\beta)\mu + \beta y_{t-1} + \big[e_t + (\theta-\beta)e_{t-1} - \theta \beta e_{t-2} + u_t \big]$$

Taking help of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/535468/239481), I need to show that there's an equivalent MA(2) process, say $v_t+\theta_1 v_{t-1} + \theta_2 v_{t-2}$ which has same covariance function as the process in square brackets above. It turns out to be very messy:
\begin{align}
\sigma^2_e(1+(\theta - \beta)^2+\theta^2 \beta^2) + \sigma^2_u &= \sigma_v^2(1+\theta_1^2+\theta_2^2) \\
(\theta - \beta)(1-\beta\theta)\sigma_e^2 &= \sigma_v^2(\theta_1 + \theta_1 \theta_2) \\
-\theta \beta \sigma_e^2 &= \theta_2 \sigma_v^2
\end{align}

2. The second part requires deriving conditions for invertibility. Given the non-linear equations above, it seems difficult to get actual $\theta_1, \theta_2$, let alone factorizing further to get characteristic roots.

Is there a simpler way to check this which I am missing?